# Regex to match exact string (do not allow terminating newline)

Tags: regex

In .NET *System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex* if `^` and `$` are added to the Regex to look for exact matches, it still returns true for IsMatch if a terminating `\n` is appended to the string being verified.

For example, the following code:

```
Regex regexExact = new Regex(@"^abc$");
Console.WriteLine(regexExact.IsMatch("abc"));
Console.WriteLine(regexExact.IsMatch("abcdefg"));
Console.WriteLine(regexExact.IsMatch("abc\n"));
Console.WriteLine(regexExact.IsMatch("abc\n\n"));
```

returns:

```
true
false
true
false
```

What is the Regex that will return false for all of the above except the first?

Comment: Why would you need regex for this then?  Just look to see if the string is exactly "abc"?

Comment: It could be that the real pattern is not a constant.

Comment: @maccettura I'm providing a simple example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution for the current .NET regex

You should use the very end of string anchor  that is `\z` in .NET regex:

```
Regex regexExact = new Regex(@"^abc\z");
```

See [Anchors in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions):

> `$`    The match must occur at the end of the string or line, or before `\n` at the end of the string or line. For more information, see [End of String or Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#End).
> `\Z`    The match must occur at the end of the string, or before \n at the end of the string. For more information, see [End of String or Before Ending Newline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#EndOrNOnly).
> `\z`    The match must occur at the end of the string only. For more information, see [End of String Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#EndOnly).

**The same anchor can be used in [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre), [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) and [php](/questions/tagged/php)**. In [python](/questions/tagged/python), use `\Z`. In JavaScript *`RegExp`* (ECMAScript) compatible patterns, the `$` anchor matches the very end of string (if no `/m` modifier is defined).

## Background

see [Strings Ending with a Line Break](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#realend) at regular-expressions.info:

> Because Perl returns a string with a newline at the end when reading a line from a file, Perl's regex engine matches `$` at the position before the line break at the end of the string even when multi-line mode is turned off. Perl also matches `$` at the very end of the string, regardless of whether that character is a line break. So `^\d+$` matches `123` whether the subject string is `123` or `123\n`.
>
> **Most modern regex flavors have copied this behavior. That includes .NET, Java, PCRE, Delphi, PHP, and Python**. This behavior is independent of any settings such as "multi-line mode".
>
> In all these flavors except Python, `\Z` also matches before the final line break. **If you only want a match at the absolute very end of the string, use `\z`** (lower case z instead of upper case Z). `\A\d+\z` does not match `123\n`. `\z` matches after the line break, which is not matched by the shorthand character class.
>
> In Python, `\Z` matches only at the very end of the string. Python does not support `\z`.

Comment: Nice, to mention the difference in Python.