# RegEx for ABC_XYZ_PPQRST-AA

Tags: c#, regex

I need to create a regex to test below kind of data,

```
xxx_yyy_zzz-aaa
```

I am able to verify the first two _ underscore, but unable to append the - hyphens.

```
@"[a-zA-Z0-9]_[a-zA-Z0-9]_[a-zA-Z0-9]s/[^-][a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

I am using c#. the number of characters above are just for an example

Comment: Some char are special and need escape..with a `\\`

Comment: @fubo, Yes you are right

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches a *single* character. Add `{3}` to match exactly 3

Comment: I had tried with \ i.e. escape.
I'm not sure why its not working

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/DLiuxM/1

Comment: @PawanDubey, it seems like you are missing the basic here. May I recommend you to read [this](https://regexone.com/) step by step tutorial then to pratice and debug your regex on a [online regex debugger](https://regex101.com/) like this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xxx_yyy_zzz-aaa` string implies that the format is `{alphanum}_{alphanum}_{alphanum}-{alphanum}`. The pattern for the `{alphanum}` part has already been written by you.

Next, you want to [*quantify*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) each alphanumeric part since just `[A-Za-z0-9]` matches a single alphanum char. Use `+` to match 1 or more occurrences, or `{3}` to match only 3, or `{3,}` to match 3 or more.

That is not all, since you expect the whole string to match the pattern. Hence, you need [*anchors*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), `^` to match the start of string and `$` (or [`\z`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831983/regex-to-match-exact-string-do-not-allow-terminating-newline/48832215#48832215)) to match the end of string.

Thus, I'd recommend

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b_%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b_%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b-%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b%5cz&i=xxx_yyy_zzz-aaa).