# find terminate word using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find if word terminate with 's or 'm or 're using regular expression in c#.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(word, "/$'s|$'re|$'m/"))
   textbox1.text=word;
```

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch(word, "'([sm]|re)$")`

Comment: I want if the word is: I'm, she's, he's, we're, ...etc, go to for loop to bring the next word.

Comment: Ulugbek Umirov, thank you very mach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/$'s|$'re|$'m/` .NET regex matches 3 alternatives:

- `/$'s` - `/` at the end of a string after which `'s` should follow (this will never match as there can be no text after the end of a string)
- `$'re` - end of string and then `'re` must follow (again, will never match)
- `$'m/` - end of string with `'m/`  to follow (again, will never match).

In a .NET regex, [regex delimiters are not used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31560118/3832970), thus the first and last `/` are treated as literal chars that the engine tries to match.

The `$` anchor signalize the end of a string and using anything after it makes the pattern match no string (well, unless you have a trailing `\n` after it, but that is an edge case that rarely causes any trouble). Just FYI: to [match the very end of string in a .NET regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832215/3832970), use `\z`.

What you attempted to write was

```
Regex.IsMatch(word, "'(?:s|re|m)$")
```

Or, if you put single character alternatives into a single [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
Regex.IsMatch(word, "'(?:re|[sm])$")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%28%3F%3Are%7C%5Bsm%5D%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=I%27m%0D%0Ashe%27s%0D%0Ahe%27s%0D%0Awe%27re&o=m).

**Details**

- `'` - a single quote
- `(?:`  - start of a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do):

  - `re` - the `re` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `[sm]` - a character class matching `s` or `m`
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Why do you have `$` in the end of pattern? OP says *if **word** terminate* - not a string. :)

Comment: @JohnyL See [OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685367/find-terminate-word-using-regular-expression/53695310?noredirect=1#comment94227635_53685367): *go to for loop to bring the next word.* OP is testing "words" as **separate strings** against the regex.