# Regular expresion c# for only digits 0-9 is accepting special character \n sign

Tags: c#, regex

I want to make regular expresion that will only accept string that are 4 or 6 digit long, and won`t accept any other characters.

I have code like this:

```
public static bool ValidatePin(string pin)
{
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"(^[0-9]{4}$)|(^[0-9]{6}$)");
    return rx.IsMatch(pin);
}
```

Prety simple, but when I call:

```
Console.WriteLine(Kata.ValidatePin("1246\n"));
```

It returns `true`, it seems to not omit special character `\n`. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: `$` matches either the end of string or the location before the final newline in  a string. Use `\z` to match the real end of string only

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for help. I didn`t know that and spent some time to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832215/3832970) with  more details.

Comment: Has been mentioned already to use `\z`. You can further make it a bit shorter: `^\d{4}(?:\d\d)?\z`